# How to retrieve updated stock quantity after modifying source item repository?

Tags: magento2, product, stock, out-of-stock

I am trying to add stock quantity dynamically and use the current stock quantity for adding the product to the cart. The stock quantity gets updated successfully, however the ProductRepository keeps returning the outdated stock quantity, therefore I keep getting "out of stock" exception. What's the proper way to achieve this?

```
if ($stockItem->getQuantity() - $params["qty"] <= 0) {
        $sourceItem = $this->sourceItemFactory->create();
        $sourceItem->setSourceCode('default');
        $sourceItem->setSku($product->getSku());
        $sourceItem->setQuantity(floatval($params["qty"])+$stockItem->getQuantity()+1);
        $sourceItem->setStatus(1);
        $this->sourceItemsSaveInterface->execute([$sourceItem]);
        // The following part throws an exception (out of stock)
        $this->quote->addProduct($product, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reindex the product, this will help to update the product quantity

```
protected $indexerRegistry;
    public function __construct(
        IndexerRegistry $indexerRegistry
    ) {
        $this->indexerRegistry = $indexerRegistry;
    }
    public function getVersion()
    {
        .........
        $this->indexerRegistry->get('catalog_product_category')->reindexRow($product->getId());
        .........
    }
```